# Return an object greater or less in where() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have an issue about the where() function in Underscore.js .
I have an object like this:

```
var location = [{ id: "1", name: "house 1", date: "20-11-2013" },
                { id: "2", name: "house 2", date: "30-11-2013"}];
```

And a form which works as a filter with a select like this:

```
From
<input type="date" name="from" />

Until
<input type="date" name="until" />
```

How can I make a where() function return the objects which the date is greater than the From value and less than the Until value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can't do this using `where`. You could use `filter`<sup>[doc](http://underscorejs.org/#filter)</sup> instead :

```
var fromDate, untilDate;
fromDate = $('[name="from"]').val();
fromDate = fromDate.split('-');
fromDate = new Date(fromDate[0], fromDate[1] - 1, fromDate[2]);
untilDate = $('[name="until"]').val();
untilDate = untilDate.split('-');
untilDate = new Date(untilDate[0], untilDate[1] - 1, untilDate[2]);
var result = _.filter(location, function (item) {
    var date;
    date = item.date.split('-');
    date = new Date(date[2], date[1] - 1, date[0]);
    return date > fromDate && date < untilDate; 
});
```

Comment: Would `lt` and `gt` work for dates? Wouldn't you have to convert them into date objects first, otherwise it's just comparing strings..

Comment: yes, man. Im searching in the underscore`s core and guess that I can`t do this at all. think im going to use the where and with the array that returns ill use the filter to do that. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, I gave it a shot too without using underscore and came up with this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rjRrH/).

Comment: @Andy Thanks for sharing. Don't forget to subtract 1 from the month in your parser : `return new Date(d[2], d[1] - 1, d[0]);` ;)